# How do you examine the arguments passed to a delegate?

Tags: c#, delegates

I'm trying to make a class to handle invoking methods on a remote server using my own means. To make it easier on the client caller, I'm writing a generic class that accepts an interface so that the compiler will know the number of arguments and the return type of the method.

```
public class Service<TInterface>
{
    public TResult Invoke<TResult>(Func<TInterface, TResult> function)
    {
        // Do the work
    }
}
```

So the idea is they could reference an assembly that has the interfaces, for example:

```
public interface ICalculator
{
    int Add(int num1, int num2);
}
```

And then they could write code to hit the service like this:

```
var addend = new Service<ICalculator>(/* constructor */).Invoke(s => s.Add(3, 4));
```

The problem is that in the first code block, I need to know how to find out what arguments they passed in their lamda expression. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way to do that is to take an `Expression<Func<TInterface,TResult>` instead; this is then trivial to pull apart. In fact, you can just lift my code [from here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/trunk/protobuf-net.Extensions/ServiceModel/Client/ProtoClientExtensions.cs) which covers most scenarios. In particular, look at `ResolveMethod`. Some discussion/explanation for this is [here](http://marcgravell.blogspot.com/2009/03/explaining-expression.html).

Comment: Right on, buddy. That was it. =)